# How do I select columns from pandas dataframe that have an average value greater than some limit?

Tags: python, pandas, columnsorting

I have a data frame with multiple columns. Each column is a time series of some variable. I only want to pick columns that are significant (by some metric), i.e. I want to pick a subset of columns, s.t. for each column,

1. the average(over all rows) is greater than x, or
2. the max (over all rows) is greater than x

   i  | col1 | col2 | col3 | ....

   0  |  0.1  | 0.5.  |  0.3. | ....

   1  |  .09 | 0.4   |  0.4  | ....

   2  |  .08 | .45  |  .36 | ...

Let's say, from the table above, I want to pick only [col2, col3] (with a condition:  column_avg > 0.2 ).

Or, only col2, with a condition: column_avg>.4.

And similarly, instead of being conditional on the avg, make it conditional on min or max for each column

Comment: `x` is the same for all columns?

Comment: Yes. same condition over all columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
df2 = df[df.columns[df.mean(axis=0) > 0.2]]
df3 = df[df.columns[df.max(axis=0) > 0.4]]
```

`df.min` works the same way.

Comment: Why no just use
`df2 = df.loc[:,df.mean(axis=0) > 0.2]` ?
I think its more straightforward than taking df.columns

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get every column with a mean over `.4`:

```
means = df.mean()
x = .4
useful_cols = [ind for m,ind in zip(means,means.index) if m>x]
df2 = df[useful_cols]
```

With `max` you replace `df.mean()` for `df.max()`

Please tell me if there's something that needs explanation here.